# How to show TCP listenings and filter them by local IP on Windows?

Tags: windows, networking

Server has numerous IP addresses, set up on it's network interface.

How to find, who is listening to specific IP port 80?

`netstat` shows very long list. Are there any builtin means?

**UPDATE**

Also can't use `findstr` with also wishing to know process name because brocess name is displayed on separate line.

Comment: Are built-ins required? gnuwin32 tools have the basic core utils for unix ported for windows and can easily parse the output (eg grep with -A or -B).

Answer (score 5):

one way is to run:

```
netstat -o
```

should help make the list a little shorter

or to be even more specific you can probably run

```
netstat -aon | findstr :80
```

powershell might be needed.